# Sending gapi access_token to server

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-api-client

When using Googles JavaScript API to auth a user, I would like to send the `access_token` to the server, and continue grabbing information using the `access_token` retrived by the JavaScript API.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handler);

...

function handler(result) {
    console.log("Access token: " + result.access_token);
}
```

The login works just fine, the handler function is called, and I'm able to access the `access_token`. Once it has been sent to the server, it's not able to use the `access_token`. The server is using https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to communicate with Google. The API returns an error saying that the `access_token` has expired, but it was generated just seconds ago.

Both client/server side uses the same settings (clientId, apiKey and scope).

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Login the user using javascript (window popup)
2. Send the `access_token` to server
3. Use the `access_token` server-side, i.e. retrieve account data (Google Analytics for example).